# Center vertical align <a> inside <ul><li>

Tags: css

Like the title, I want to vertical align center a `<a>` inside `<ul><li>`. Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trongcuong1710/gvTLw/)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant? http://jsfiddle.net/gvTLw/4/

Comment: No, it's not that. You can reference at @Andy answer, he solved my question. Thank for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact you are specifying heights on both elements, this can easily be achieved by adding `margin-top: 0.5em` to `a`.

[Like This](http://jsfiddle.net/gvTLw/3/)

This is because the `li` has a height of 3em, the `a` has a height of 2em, so it needs half an em at the top to look vertically centered

Answer (score 1):

Change the line-height of the `a` to match the line-height of the `li`.

```
a {
    /*...preceding styles */
    line-height: 3em; /* Elements line-height set to match parents */
    height: 2em;
    width: 5em;     
    text-align: center;
}
```

**OR**

Set the property `vertical-align:middle` on the `a`.

```
a{
   /*...Other styles ommitted*/
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/gvTLw/5/

Comment: It didn't work as expected, you can recheck [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trongcuong1710/gvTLw/6/), hover your mouse on `<a>` and you'll see, it only pushes the text to bottom of `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the height and line-height of the `a` element to match the height of the `li`:

```
li {
    height: 3em;
}

a {
    line-height: 3em;
    height: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Kevin's response, setting line-height on the anchor to `inherit` will do the same thing, without having to match the value manually

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IckleChris/rnNMJ/1/)